# How to change a datasource's username/password at runtime in a Java EE app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource

I've deployed a web-module which connects to the database via a datasource configured in the Java EE application server.

Currently, the user/password for the database connection is set in the proper Java EE application server's datasources configuration file.

I want to change during runtime the datasource's user/password. (e.g.: implement a new web form in which the user is asked to enter de user/password to be used in the database connection).

Is there a standard way to do that in Java EE applications or it depends on the Java EE application server? In this case I'm using [Orion application server](http://www.orionserver.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataSource has a [getConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method that takes a username and password. That seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: The link is down!

Answer (score 0):

The management of data sources is not standardized. You have to use your AS' API, if it provides any for this a bit unusual use case.